# RDLC - Can i change property of a row which displayed by detail group in table?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

Is there any way to determine and change property of a row in a rdlc which displayed by details group?

> I have a table display like this: 
>    Col1   Col2
>    
> ----------------
>    1            2
>    
> ----------------
>    1            2
>    
> ----------------
>    5            6
>    
> ----------------

Can I dertermine the second row or any row i want and change the property of that row like this?

> Col1   Col2
>    
> ----------------
>    1            2
>    
> ----------------
>    1            2
>    
> **__________**< i want this line not dashed any more
>    5            6
>    
> ----------------

Thanks

Comment: Did this work out for you? If so, glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. I thought i just have to click the solved button to notify that is a correct answer and not left any comment, sorry for that( I'm working on my english too :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [RowNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252081%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function and put an expression in the BorderStyle property.

The RowNumber function requires a string argument, which can be the name of the Table (or Tablix etc) where your data is displayed. For this example, I'll assume you have added a Tablix to your report and its name is "Tablix1". Now you can use the RowNumber function in an expression in the details row like this:

`=RowNumber("Tablix1")`

And that expression will evaluate to the current row number. I used that expression in the first column of the table shown below to generate the numbers in the column labeled "Row" (this is just for your understanding of the RowNumber function, and it is not necessary to have this column in your report).

Now, to affect the lines between rows or any other propery of a detail row, all you have to do is test for the RowNumber in the expression for that property. So for your example of changing the cell border, here's what you need to do:

1. Select the cells you want to be affected (e.g. the whole detail row)
2. In the properties window, expand the BorderStyle property so you can see Top,Bottom etc
3. Set the Top BorderStyle to be "None"
4. Set the Bottom BorderStyle to be the following expression:

   > `=IIF(RowNumber("Tablix1")=3, "Solid", "Dashed")`
5. Make sure the BorderWidth is set to 1 (or more) and the BorderColor is set to some color  (NOT Empty or Transparent)

Important: Make sure you change the argument to RowNumber (e.g. "Tablix1") to match the exact name of the table that the detail row is in. Otherwise this will not work. (See the documentation for RowNumber for additional information about other scopes you can use.)

Those changes will cause Row 3 to have a solid bottom border and other cells to have dashed bottom borders as shown in the image below. We had to set the top border to "None" because otherwise it would have potentially overdrawn the bottom border, masking the effect.

[image: Report Example]

As an example of a slightly different variation, I posted a table below in which the expression for the **Color** property (i.e. text color) was set to the expression `=IIF(RowNumber("Tablix1") < 4, "Black", "Red")`. As you can see, rows 1-3 have black text, while rows 4 and beyond have red text.

[image: Report Example 2]

You can use the RowNumber function to modify any property of a detail row using the same principle described above. Just make sure to use the correct "scope" argument.